# Is it possible to create a dynamic array without explicitly defining a variable to specify the length?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I’m trying to create a dynamic array which can be modified using the functions `Array_Push(array, val)` & `Array_Del(array, index)`. Now the current way I have this I need a variable to keep track of the size of it. My implementation of this concept is to store the data/size in a struct like so:

```
struct Array {  
    int *data;  
    int size;  
}
```

In order to read the actual array you have to type `array.data[i]` which I think is a little bit redundant.

My solution to this was attempting to store the size of the array in a different index. I didn’t want to store it inside `[0]` as that would create a lot of confusion, so I wanted to try storing it inside of `[-1]`. An obvious problem with this is that `[-1]` is outside the array. What I did instead was create an array via `int *array = malloc(sizeof(int))`. After that I increment the pointer to it via `array += 1`. However when I try to free it with `free(array)`, I end up freeing non `malloc()`ed memory. My current thoughts are that the problem lies somewhere in that when I call `malloc()` inside a function it doesn't modify my original pointer. If this were the case then  I was wondering how I could fix this so it does. Here is my code in case it helps:

array.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *Array_Create() {
  int *array = malloc(sizeof(int));

  // If malloc fails to allocate memory
  if (array == NULL) {
    printf("Error creating array: malloc() failed to allocate memory");
    exit(12);
  }

  array[0] = 0;

  array += 1;

  return array;
}

void Array_Push(int *array, int value) {
  if (array[-1] == 0) {
    array = malloc(sizeof(int));
  } else {
    // array = realloc(array, sizeof(int) * array[-1]);
    printf("ERROR READING ARRAY SIZE IN: Array_Push()");
  }
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <dynamic_array.h>

int main() {
  int *array = Array_Create();

  printf("%d", array[-1]);

  Array_Push(array, 1);

  free((array - 1));
  free(array);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the initial struct. You are making simple things far too complicated here, which is poor engineering. I would take a step back from this and instead pick the simplest implementation, using well-established best practices in C.

Comment: I'm aware there's nothing wrong with it. I just find it mildly redundent to have that, so I wanted to attempt to fix it. My question is simply: Is it possible?. And if so then: could you please explain to me how?.

Comment: The correct solution isn't trying to "fix" C but to use it as it is. However, the least ugly fix given some `typedef struct { ... }  array; array arr;` would probably be to use a macro: `#define arr arr.data`. And how you can type `arr[i]`.

Comment: @Debuholden, `array = malloc(sizeof(int));` in `Array_Push()` serves no purpose other than to allocate memory and then leak it.  The new assignment of `array` does not affect the calling code in any way.

Comment: @Debuholden, If you wanted a "dynamic array" of `char`, would its dynamic length get limited to `CHAR_MAX`?  Presently your "dynamic array" of `int` size is limited to `INT_MAX`, yet true array size limits are of the order of `SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your uses of `malloc` and `free` suggest you think individual elements of an array can be allocated and freed, or you have some other conceptual error about memory allocation.

`malloc` gives you an address of block of memory, and you must pass that same address to `free`. You cannot pass any other address in that block to `free`. It is fine to add one to the address and use that for your indexing, but, when you pass an address to `free`, you must reconstruct the original address by subtracting one.

`Array_Create` can be:

```
int *Array_Create(void)
{
    int *array = malloc(sizeof *array);
    if (!array)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating array:  malloc failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    array[0] = 0;
    return array +1;
}
```

and `Array_Push` can be:

```
int *Array_Push(int *array, int value)
{
    int *temp = realloc(array-1, (array[-1] + 1) * sizeof *temp);
        // Note use of array-1 when passing address to realloc.
    if (!temp)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error growing array:  realloc failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    array = temp+1;
    ++array[-1];
    array[0] = value;
    return array;
}
```

When you free the array, you should use only `free(array-1)`, not `free(array)`.

Note that `Array_Push` needs to provide a new value for `array`, so I wrote it to return that value. When you call it, it should be called as `array = Array_Push(array, value);`. It could also be written to accept a pointer to `array`, as in `void Array_Push(int **array, int value);` and called as `Array_Push(&array, value);`. This requires corresponding changes to its code.

That said, this sort of arrangement is avoided by good programmers, for reasons of design, engineering, and quality that are beyond the scope of this answer. This sort of code might be used in some situations, but you generally want to avoid kludges like this.

Comment: @nielsen: Oops, missed that, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: placing `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` in library code if not the most encouraged practice.

Comment: @tstanisl: It is not library code, and Stack Overflow is for answering specific questions, not providing finished production code. Code in answers should be focused on the specific question.

Comment: I agree that it does not matter here. But still it is worth to mention that placing a hidden `exit()` call is not a good practice.

Comment: @tstanisl: It is not universally “not a good practice.” It depends on the application. I have no interest in people pushing novice theories of design. Realize that not everybody practices in the particular subdomain of programming that you do, and not every program should be written to handle all possible events in whatever particular way you want them handled. Not every program needs to handle all possible input or try to recover from all possible failures.

Comment: Would you mind adding in an example of using pointers?